# Markdown discrepancy between live preview and finished posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

(I'm not sure I'm right on this meta site, but since there's a `bug` tag...)

The following is a link to a web page with a trailing `)` in its URL:

[test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_(disambiguation))

I know, the parentheses can be escaped, but that's not the issue here.

---

It's markdown live preview looks like this (apart from the actual URL):

[test](http://www.example.com))

I.e. the trailing `)` of the URL is thought of as the close parenthesis of the markdown code.

Now, if everything goes as I remember, the finished post will have a link that looks like this:

[test](http://www.example.com)

Therefore, the server-side markdown parser behavior is different from the JS live preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some minor discrepancies between the preview and the final post.

This one in particular is because the JavaScript regular expressions can't quite deal with recursive parens -- but the server-side can.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to reduce the server-side feature set then, to match the behaviors of both systems as good as possible? While this would require work-arounds to make these kinds of links work, at least the preview would prepare the user adequately for how the post turns out.

Comment: @daniel preview is like the viewfinder on your camera. It gives you a reasonable idea of how your photo will turn out but it's not pixel-exact.

Comment: Fortunately, you can make “free/test” edits for up to five minutes before questions and answers are locked in so that further edits trigger a revision (editing a comment *always* causes an edit icon to be added).