# Error with question preview

Tags: support, preview

[My question](https://superuser.com/q/330976/81403) if you click "edit" and look at the preview you'll see that it is very different from the actual view.  In the preview you see a hyperlinked  but when you go to the actual question, you don't see it at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1754/markdown-discrepancy-between-live-preview-and-finished-posts

Comment: Similar idea, but not exact (it seems like there is a general version of the bug)

Comment: @soandos It's a completely different issue, but both are caused by the live preview being a separate implementation from the server-side once. It seems that as long as it's close enough, it's good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put

`Http`

instead of

`http`

We only recognize the all lower case version as a valid URL.

Comment: Why is it that way?

Comment: why shouldn't it be that way?

Comment: I have no issue myself with it, I only ever use lowercase. But why doesn't the system accept Http or say, HTTP? Is it just bevauae lower case is the formal way of writing it?

Comment: Even if that is the case, there should be no difference between the preview and the real thing.

Comment: Why is there a difference between the preview and the real thing?