# Link seems fixed in edit preview, but still broken in actual answer

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown discrepancy between live preview and finished posts](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1754/markdown-discrepancy-between-live-preview-and-finished-posts)

The second link in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/387898/36744) ends with a closing parenthesis, which seems to be an issue. So I edited it and tried to fix it by placing a backslash before the closing parenthesis. Which fixes the issue in the preview dialog. But when I save my change, the link in the actual answer is still broken.

**Edit**
Please note that the closing parenthesis is part of the link:
[image: In edit dialog]

**Resulting post**
Please note that the closing parenthesis is no longer part of the link:
[image: In post]

Comment: FYI, I've taken the liberty of fixing it for you, so the post will not appear broken to new visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets at the end of "raw" links cause a problem.

Use the 'named' link syntax, like so:

```
* [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(command)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(command))
```

or

```
* [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(command)][1]

...more document...

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(command)
```

Comment: My main concern wasn't that the link is broken but the difference between preview and result. The preview is misleading. But thanks for telling me how to fix it, as that would have been my second question ;)

Comment: (Sorry for slow response, ended up in a meeting) And I'm seeing the difference only appears on the preview when you attempt to escape the url with a `\`? Strange.